# Did the lifetime of c_str() changed between g++ 4.8.4 and g++ 5.3.1?

Tags: c++, string, g++, g++4.8, g++5.1

I start processes from a daemon which makes sure that said processes run continuously and get started in the proper order, etc.

At some point, I want to start the process with `execv()` so I prepare an array of string for the arguments as so:

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
args.push_back("--debug");
args.push_back("--connect");
args.push_back("10.0.0.5:4040");
...
```

In most cases, I have around 10 such arguments.

Now, `execv()` only access an array of bare pointers. So I do the following to create an array of such pointers:

```
std::vector<char *> args_p; // sorry, my code actually uses std::vector<char const *> args_p -- so constness is fine here
for(auto a : args)
{
    args_p.push_back(a.c_str());
}
args_p.push_back(nullptr); // list needs to be null terminated
```

Then I can call `execv()` with that last array:

```
execv(
    args_p[0],
    const_cast<char * const *>(&args_p[0])
);
```

That was working perfectly in Ubuntu 14.04 with g++ 4.8.4, but somehow, the `c_str()` pointers get invalidated when I try to run the same code compiled with g++ 5.3.1.

From my understanding, this should not be since I do not modify the strings between the first loop which creates the array of bare pointers and the `execv()` call.

The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) says:

> The pointer obtained from c_str() may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and rend().

**P.S.** I already have a fix, I now do an `stdup()` of the `c_str()` and it works just fine that way. Only I was hoping to avoid one extra copy of the string if possible...

Comment: It never worked. It just appeared to. You have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, it should be `auto const & a : args`, and that works!

Comment: @BaummitAugen Why delete your answer?

Comment: @Barry I think gcc new string ABI wasn't on by default until gcc 6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

```
for(auto a : args)
{
    args_p.push_back(a.c_str());
}
```

First, `c_str()` returns a `char const*` and `args_p` is a `vector<char*>`. Since you need a pointer to non-`const` `char`, you'll have to use `&a[0]`.

Second, `a` goes out of scope at the end of each iteration of the loop. So the pointer that you're holding onto will get destroyed out from under you. You need the pointers into the actual strings in `args` - so you'll need to iterate by reference:

```
for(auto& a : args)
{
    args_p.push_back(&a[0]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake here, the array of bare pointers is `char const *`. The main problem is that the `auto a : args` would make a copy of the string and that copy "disappears" on each iteration. It is strange that it ever worked actually. I tried now with `auto const & a : args` and it works fine without the `strdup()`. Just like before!

Comment: Will the string be null terminated (with a `'\0'`) if I use just `&a[0]`?

Comment: `&a[0]` fails for empty strings . Maybe not an issue if the code guarantees the vector didn't contain any empty strings but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: @M.M Fixed the temporary part. The other part is I guess moot since OP wanted a `const char*` anyway.

Comment: Yeah, and a `vector<const char *>` instead of casting the non-const vector's contents!